# Silverlight 4: Any touch library that supports gestures & touch events?

Tags: silverlight, multi-touch

Silverlight provides only Touch.FrameReported event and doesnt provide any events for the UIElements like it does for mouse events(ex: MouseDown, MouseUp). Is there any touch library available for the silverlight which provides these touch events and supports gestures.

Google did not help me much or may be my search terms are not correct. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some useful stuff, but it is nowhere near a complete library:

http://www.jebishop.com/2009/11/05/multi-touch-gesture-recognition-in-silverlight-3/

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336026.aspx its all about multi-touch support for silverlight